# Parse JSON in Swift3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

Using below code to parse JSON , facing issue

```
 let result = "{
    status = ok;
    token = XXXXX;
}"
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: (result as? Data)! , options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions())
                    print("Further data \(json)")
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

            }
```

Facing below exception:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x111789238) to
>   'NSData' (0x1117882e8). (lldb)

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: did you google for the error and for an working example?

Comment: Your result is already dictionary. There is no need to use `JSONSerialization` with it

Comment: This is not JSON.

Comment: (result as? Data)!  -- You cant convert like this.  'result' is dictionary. you need to pass 'NSData'

Comment: @NiravD It would appear that result is actually a string, although it wouldn't compile with as-is with multiple lines.  It's not JSON either.

Comment: @JAL From the code it is look like `string` but as error saying result is Dictionary. So i'm suggesting is to use directly that.

Comment: found the solution by doing just like below    let data = result as! NSDictionary

Comment: You should conditionally cast the returned data and use nil coalescing operator to assign an empty dictionary in case of failure `let jsonDict = result as? [String:Any] ?? [:]`

Answer (score 1):

First, JSON format is not correct. It should as

```
{  
"status":"ok",
"token":"XXXXX"
}
```

Second, You are trying typecast string into NSData which is not possible. Issue is at

```
(result as? Data)!
```

Rather you should do it like this:

```
let resultData = result.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```